# iOS - Change button color after button press does not work

Tags: ios, uibutton, cgcontext, uicolor

I used the code found [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/improved-gradient-buttons.html) to color my buttons. I've created some methods similar to those in the code for default coloring such as `orangeColor`, `greenColor` and so on.

When My view loads I set the color of my UIButtons, and when one is pressed I want to change the color of the buttons to reflect their change in function, I do the following (considering the buttons are a different color):

```
[self.recordPlayButton greenColor];
[self.recordPlayButton setNeedsDisplay];
[self.stopRecordButton orangeColor];
[self.stopRecordButton setNeedsDisplay];
```

But the color of my buttons remains the same, any idea why this happens?

**EDIT:** another odd thing I just noticed is that the highlight color for the button changes but not the normal color.

Comment: Try NSLog in the function to verify that your method is calling on button  click.

Comment: When debugging I can see that the code is getting called, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/issues/detail?id=4

If you look at the Wiki for the gradient buttons, you can see that it's actually defect in iOS5. Have you tested if the demo works on your device?

Comment: You sent me the wrong issue, I checked and found the one that you meant, thank you. You should edit the answer to point to the right issue.